# Display User Input from one activity to another in a textView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity, android-edittext

I tried to display User Input from my main activity to my second activity, but when I typed in and click the send button on the main activity the whole app just crashes. Please help!

**crash solved! Thanks a lot!**
However, I can't get the message to display on the second activity.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.dell_inspiron.sendmessage;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import static android.R.id.message;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final String message = getResources().getString(R.string.UserInput);

    final Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent sendMessage = new Intent(MainActivity.this,     DisplayMessageActivity.class);
            sendMessage.putExtra("UserInput", message);
            startActivity(sendMessage);

        }
    });
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.dell_inspiron.sendmessage.MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="@string/edit"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/UserInput" />

<Button
    android:text="@string/send"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/UserInput"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:id="@+id/send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**DisplayMessageActivity.java**

```
package com.example.dell_inspiron.sendmessage;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    Intent Extra = getIntent();
    String textView = Extra.getStringExtra("UserInput");

    TextView UserInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.UserOutput);
    UserInput.setText(textView);



    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            launchActivity();

        }
    });
}

private void launchActivity() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

**activity_display_message.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_display_message"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.dell_inspiron.sendmessage.DisplayMessageActivity">

<Button
    android:text="@string/Button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="51dp"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/UserOutput"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="91dp"
    android:id="@+id/UserOutput" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/enter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/enter"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_purple" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your stacktrace

Comment: Sorry I'm really new to this, can you tell me what is stacktrace?

Comment: you should post the logcat output when app crashes.

Comment: @ZhimingZhao look like this https://www.google.com/search?q=logcat+android&rlz=1C1CHBF_enMY714MY714&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLhrWuoMnRAhXFRo8KHewvCFsQ_AUICigD&biw=1366&bih=662#imgrc=_h3B2Q8JFvMnPM%3A

Comment: Did any answer helped?

Comment: [Go through this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2091482/5134647)
and please check if your question is already answered or not before posting your own

Comment: @John Joe The crash was fixed by changing int to string, but i still cant display the message

Comment: @ZhimingZhao update your post to the latest so we know what the problem you facing.

Comment: @John Joe I did update it

Comment: @ZhimingZhao solution updated.Check it and let me know whether it works or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `int`, but receive it in `String`, so your app crashed.

**MainActivity**

```
 int message = R.string.UserInput;
    Intent sendMessage = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    sendMessage.putExtra("UserInput", message);
```

**DisplayMessageActivity**

```
Bundle Extra = getIntent().getExtras();
String textView = Extra.getString("UserInput");
```

You should also add

```
intent.putExtra("UserInput", message);
```

into `launchActivity` method.

**Solution 1**

Change `String textView = Extra.getString("UserInput");` to `int textView= Extra.getIntExtra("UserInput", 0);`

**Solution 2**

To send the message to your second Activity, you need to use intent inside your MainActivity button click. Modify your code as below.

```
package com.example.dell_inspiron.sendmessage;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import static android.R.id.message;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String message = getResources().getString(R.string.UserInput);

    final Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {
        public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent sendMessage = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DisplayMessageActivity.class);
         sendMessage.putExtra("UserInput", message);
         startActivity(sendMessage);
        }
    });
}
}
```

**Solution 3**

This line look wrong to me

```
final String message = getResources().getString(R.string.UserInput);
```

If you want to get the `editText` string, this is the way to go

```
EditText input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.UserInput);  // declare your editText

final String message = input.getText().toString();  // get your input type
```

Comment: But I want to recieve string, shouldn't I use string textview?

Comment: Then you should use `String` message in MainActivity instead of `int` message. What is R.string.UserInput?

Comment: it is string, and I fixed it

Comment: check the solution 2

Comment: It did not display the message on the second activity

Comment: Add a Toast and see message display anything or not.

Comment: Then I'll need to learn about toast, it may take awhile. When I got updates I will tell you. Thanks for the time that you gave me!

Comment: Just add `Toast.makeText(getApplication(),message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` inside your button click.

Comment: I did some research about toast, it's like a floating message that disappears after a time period. But I want my message to be on the screen permanently.

Comment: check my answer again (Solution 3).

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you are getting the user input from the MainActivity but i don't see anything like that in your code but you can do the below to pass some value from one activity to another...

Change your second activity like this

```
Bundle Extra = getIntent().getExtras();
String textView = Extra.getString("UserInput");
```

to

```
Intent Extra = getIntent();
String textView = Extra.getStringExtra("UserInput");
```

and change your MainActivity like this

```
int message = R.string.UserInput;
```

to

```
String message= getResources().getString(R.string.UserInput);
```

and

```
final Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
      launchActivity();

    }
});
```

to

```
Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
      startActivity(sendMessage);

    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry if I make stupid mistakes since I'm really, really new to programming. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There is issue with your second Activity.You are passing int value in Intents but trying to get String value.

Change it as below:

```
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;

  public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

 Bundle Extra = getIntent().getExtras();
 int textView = Extra.getInt("UserInput");

TextView UserInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.UserInput2);
UserInput.setText(textView);

final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

{
    public void onClick(View v) {
        launchActivity();

    }
});
}

private void launchActivity() {

Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}

}
```